# Node Coffeescript doesn't self register

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to use a newer version of node (anything > 10.36) which breaks loading coffeescript on my server.

My coffeescript is loaded like

`require('coffee-script').register()`

and I get the following error:

```
/Users/mac/Dropbox/chatter-plot/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45
    Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                                 ^
Error: Module did not self-register.
```

I've tried with both coffeescript versions `1.7.1` and `1.9.1` and it makes no difference which leads me to believe I need to instantiate coffeescript differently somehow.

Can't find a relevant solution anywhere on google.

Comment: √ Works for me - Node.js 0.12 and CoffeeScript 1.9.1 . Perhaps try to load it as `require('coffee-script/register')`. It should be the same, but perhaps there is some strangeness going on.

Comment: That's what I had previously and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Removing my node_modules directory and doing an npm install worked for me.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```